# Powerpoint can't close a file

Tags: ms-office

Powerpoint has a file open that I simply can't close. If I try to, I get a white screen - and the Powerpoint Title Line - but I cannot switch windows to a different pptx. I've tried saving it with a different name, closing and reopening Powerpoint, etc. - but when I do re-open the application, there is the wretched file.

Comment: Are you running Yosemite?

Answer (score 2):

With Powerpoint quit, go to
`~/Library/Saved Application State/com.microsoft.Powerpoint.savedState/`
& delete the folder &/or contents.

Quick way to get there, if you're not sure…

- From Finder, hit  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>N</kbd>  for New Window
- Hit  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>G</kbd>  for Go…
- Paste `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.microsoft.Powerpoint.savedState/` including the tilde ~
- Delete the files you find in there, data.data, window_1.plist etc, everything, or delete the entire powerpoint.savedState folder itself.

Launch Powerpoint again.

Comment: you said "Word" in second line, it's typo?

Comment: oops, yes - fixing

Comment: I didn't have a powerpoint saved state to start with, so I used the path to word ;)